# Is the `screen name` for Google Analytics screen tracking case sensitive?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I would like to know if the `screen name` passed to the GA `Tracker` is case sensitive?

So would I be able to change

```
tracker.setScreenName("TestScreen")
tracker.send(HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build())
```

to

```
tracker.setScreenName("testscreen")
tracker.send(HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build())
```

and it shows up as the same screen?

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens) doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, screen names in GA is case sensitive. Your screen will be captured as a new screen.

You can create a custom filter on the view to lowercase the data without even modifying your app. This will help you to keep your data organized.